# Does SAP PowerDesigner have an API?

Tags: powerdesigner

Does PowerDesigner have an Java/Python etc. API that can be called so that I can retrieve a physical table's columns and data types programmatically?

Googling did not help me locate a documentation and possibly a tutorial.

Any directions would me extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The basic API for PowerDesigner uses [OLE Automation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/31c48596e34446a68956e0aa7e700a2e/16.6.2/en-US/c7d647336e1b1014b0a0bce93c2ce2a8.html).

This API is readily accessible from VBScript, .NET languages, PowerShell...

PowerDesigner comes with a helper jar named pdj2com*.jar.

You should have a `JavaProxy.doc` under the `Java Samples` sub-directory, with instructions to use this jar.

The code looks like this, from the example for the creation of an Object-Oriented Model:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM;
import com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdCommon.*;
import com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.*;

int hr = COM.OleInitialize(0);
Application pdApp = Application.getInstance();
Model newModel = new Model(pdApp.CreateModel(PdOOM_Classes.cls_Model, "|Language=Java|Diagram=ClassDiagram"));
newModel.SetName("Customer Management");
newModel.SetCode("CustomerManagement");
com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class newClass = new com.sybase.stf.powerdesigner.PdOOM.Class(newModel.GetClasses().CreateNew());
newClass.SetName("Customer");
newClass.SetCode("Customer");
```